# How to run two react projects together in my local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, yarnpkg, package.json

My project sturture is as follows :

```
Projects --- package.json 
   |-------Project1 ---- package.json
   |-------Project2 ---- package.json
```

if I run `yarn start` from `cd Projects/Project1`, project1 react app runs.

if I run `yarn start` from `cd Projects/Project2`, project2 react app runs.

for running the app from Projects, I need to specify project name : eg: `yarn start-Project1`

I want to run both my projects from the top most directory using yarn start. I want to run the projects on different ports.

If I change the `package.json` in "Projects" to this

`"start": "cd Projects/Project1 && export PORT=3001 && cd ../Project2 && export PORT=3000 && react-scripts start",`

It is only running of the project. Thank you.

Comment: I've used the [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package in the past

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `&&` operator runs commands in sequence, meaning each command runs after the previous command exits. Your Project1 doesn't exit, it just sits there running indefinitely.

You need to run both your commands in parallel. One way to do this is to use `&` instead of `&&`. `&` will start the first command in the background instead of waiting for it to exit.

When using `&` you should be careful of the order of operations. You can use parentheses to group sequential/parallel commands as necessary. I think this command might work for you:

```
(cd Projects/Project1 && export PORT=3001) & (cd ../Project2 && export PORT=3000) & react-scripts start
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to project1 path in terminal and run project1 by yarn start.
Open project2 package.json file and edit scripts section as following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start",
}
```

And run project2 by yarn start in its path too.
Hope this helps.